# Validate that at least one check_box is selected in Rails (non HABTM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, checkbox

I have a database table for the model Request that has a column that is items. Items is an array. When the user submits the form, I need a validation that ensures that the array is not empty (i.e., at least one item is checked) before they're allowed to hit submit.

I've found how to do this if item were a model that belonged to Request, but not if item is just a column within Request. Below is my best attempt, but it's not working, because I got an error `You need to supply at least one validation

Model code

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :item
  validates :must_have_one_item

  def must_have_one_item
    for item in @request.items
        errors.add(:base, 'You must select at least one item') if request.item.blank?
    end
  end
```

View form code

```
<%= f.check_box(:item, {:multiple => true}, "#{item}") %>
```

Controller code

```
def create
    @requestrecord = Request.new(request_params)
end

private
    def request_params
       params.require(:request).permit({:item => []})
    end
```

Comment: btw, you have `item` as the checkbox and `:item` in the permit, but are accessing `items` in the model code.... I recommend making them all be called `items` to reduce confusion. You are talking about a collection of items... so name them `items`

Comment: ah so i fixed this but in the reverse, i decided to call everything item since that's the table in the db. but then as i wrote in the other comment below, self.item.blank? doesn't through an error, but also doesn't actually do the check

Comment: Yeah - it'll get confused between a single item and multiple items. better to fix it to the way that's actually sensible ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... what happens is that checkboxes, when unchecked, are stored in the array as "0", so the validation fails because the array isn't technically blank.

When nothing is checked, the paramaters that are stored is
`items = ["0", "0", "0", "0"]` instead of `items=[]`

Therefore what did it was this:

```
 def must_have_one_item
     errors.add(:items, 'You must select at least one item') unless self.items.detect { |i| i != "0" } 
 end
```

Comment: This cannot possibly be the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The correct invocation of a custom validation is as follows:

```
validate :must_have_one_item
```

Note that custom validation blocks are invoked using `validate`, not *`validates`*. According to [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate), `validate` does the following:

> Adds a validation method or block to the class. This is useful when overriding the validate instance method becomes too unwieldy and you're looking for more descriptive declaration of your validations.

Contrast this with how `validates` is invoked, again, from [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates):

> This method is a shortcut to all default validators and any custom validator classes ending in 'Validator'.

Answer (score 2):

This will add an error for every item that is blank.

```
def must_have_one_item
  for item in @request.items
    errors.add(:base, 'You must select at least one item') if request.item.blank?
  end
end
```

You want to add an error if all of them are blank yes?

```
def must_have_one_item
  errors.add(:base, 'You must select at least one item') if self.items.all?{|item| item.blank? }    
end
```

or, depending on how your items operate, this might also work::

```
def must_have_one_item
  errors.add(:base, 'You must select at least one item') if self.items.blank? 
end
```

Comment: I definitely want the latter of what you're saying. But with the code (either), it throws an undefined method "items" for NilClass. I'm not sure why it's not responding to the method (which btw, I changed to if @requestrecord.items.blank? since @requestrecord = Request.new per the controller)

Comment: So - we are inside of a request already. To get the set of items, you don't need to go to a `@request` variable, but instead use `self` to refer to "the current request that we're saving right now"

Comment: Right right that makes total sense. I hate to ask again, but I'm still getting an items is undefined method error but for that specific Request. Initially I thought it was a pluralization problem, so I subbed out items with just item, but then the validation stopped working completely..

Comment: rename the column to items and it'll just magically work ;) (I hope)

Comment: ok so i renamed everything to items, and same thing, it's not throwing an error, but it's also not working. removing serialize unfortunately doesn't help either...

Comment: items undefined? have you updated the column in the database to be items too? Rails needs that part too - and I'd keep the serialize.

Comment: Start up your rails console (in terminal with `rails c`) and try: `request = Request.new(items: [])` then `request.items.inspect` If it explodes then something else is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear. I'm not getting a no method error anymore, and the console works just fine. The validation however is just non-existent. If I leave every checkbox blank the form still submits perfectly.

Comment: right - so  your create action is just doing a "new" instead of a "create"... which means it never does create one ;)

Comment: but all the other validations work... item is one of 4 other columns that work fine, how could it be singling out that one?