# f.input required for checkbox forces me to select all the boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a user sign up, he can choose the skills he has (for example: `python`) from check boxes.

I want that at least one skill/checkbox is selected before allowing the user to submit his registration.

**registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= f.input :skill, required: true, as: :check_boxes, collection:[
        ['Python', "python"],
        ['Java', "java"],
        ['JavaScript', "javascript"],
        ['Ruby', "ruby"],
        ['C++', "c++"],
        ['Node.js', "node"],
        ['React', "react"],
        ['Django', "django"],
        ['Rails', "rails"],
        ['SQL', "sql"],
        ['Doker', "doker"],
        ['AWS', "aws"],
        ['Vue.js', "vue"],
        ['Marketing', "Marketing"],
        ['HR', "hr"],
        ['Finance', "finance"],
        ['IT', "it"],
        ] %>
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_candidate!
  before_action :authenticate_interviewer!
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:skill, :firstname, :lastname, :linkedin, :angellist])
  end

end
```

It works **HOWEVER**, in the way it is now, the user cannot submit his registration unless he checks all the boxes.

I just want to "force" the user to choose at least one checkbox before allowing him to submit the form. As it is now, he has to selected all the skills/checkboxes to proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate that at least one check\_box is selected in Rails (non HABTM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626222/validate-that-at-least-one-check-box-is-selected-in-rails-non-habtm)

Comment: What happens if you remove the required true from the form, but add a validation in the user model: validates :skill, prensence: true ?

Comment: Thanks. I also tried tat approach, but the problem varies: now the user can sign up without clicking any checkbox

Comment: I would recommend to do a server side validation on your model. Link by @Jake shows exactly that. I recommned this because I am not too sure what `required: true` actually does. Can you check what params are sent when `required: true` is there or not ? Because server side validation is a must, I would recommend to implement it first. And check the behavior of `required: true` later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22626327/7372897) answer and @Maxence point out, you will need to handle your validation in the Model.

You may need to change `@registrations` to what you are specifically using to populate the form.

```
# answered by @zeantsoi - the first answer
validate :must_have_one_skill

# answered by @Taryn East - the second answer
def must_have_one_skill
  errors.add(:base, 'You must select at least one skill') if self.skills.all?{|skill| skill.blank? }    
end
```