# Rails 6: How to require at least one check box in collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-6

For most Rails form inputs you can use `required: true` to require the input.  Is there an equivalent for `collection_check_boxes`?  I have tried:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, {required: true} do |c| %>
    <%= c.check_box %>
    <%= c.label %>
<% end %>
```

This places the required on each individual check box, which is not what I'm looking for.  Is there a way to do it without a controller validation?

Comment: Javascript. The required attribute in HTML applies to single elements. If you want more advanced validation logic you need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to build a dynamic list for categories where it would have required column for example, and based on that you would pass the required: true to the specific check_box.

```
categories_hash = [{id: 1, name: 'Bananas', required: false}, {id: 2, name: 'Apples', required: true}]
```

and then it might work like this **(I did not test it)** by passing the `c[:required]` to the checkbox needed:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, categories_hash.map {|k| k[:name]}, :id, :name do |c| %>
  <%= c.check_box, required: c[:required] %>
  <%= c.label %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: There is not a specific check box that needs to be checked.  I only care that at least one box is checked

Comment: @SaraTibbetts this answer might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626222/validate-that-at-least-one-check-box-is-selected-in-rails-non-habtm